# Insert column with one row to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

I have a pandas data frame and I want to add a new column, with the last row of the first columns.
However, when I add the new column like this:

```
data_frame.insert(12, 'Sample', Counts[-1:])
```

I have a column with the row, but the index is different from 0.
Thanks for the help.

The Initial dataframe is this one:
[image]

the expected would be like this:

[image]

But instead I got this:

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is `variable`?

Comment: I edited the question, because it was not well formulated.

Comment: Are you using Pandas? And what's `Counts`?

Comment: yes,Im using pandas. Counts is a variable that counts the number of occurrences in sample A.

Comment: I've added pandas tag. Experts should soon be here :-)

Comment: can you also show your initial dataframe?

Comment: the second image is my initial dataframe

Comment: does `df["samp"] = df.Counts.iloc[-1]` work for your application? And you **have not shown an initial dataframe**. You show us an expected output and what you actually get with your attempt.

Comment: yes, it works. I have edited the question to introduce my initial data frame.